# ajax call in submit handler

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In my change password functionality, I use jquery validator for validation and ajax call for checking old password in submit handler .I have tried  AJAX in  custom rule(addMethod) in jquery for checking old password.It  gave me "Incorrect password " and "This field is required " message at the same time for empty password. Then I tried Ajax call in submit handler as below now it applying validation correctly but not checking for old password in Ajax.

```
var postUrl = "{{ URL::to('frontend/checkpassword') }}";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#passwordForm').validate({
        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true,
                password1: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8
                },
                password2: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: '#password1'
                },
            },
            messages: {
                password: {
                    required: "Please enter Old Password",
                },
                password1: {
                    required: "Please enter a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 8 characters long"
                },
                password2: {
                    required: "Please enter a password",
                    equalTo: "The two passwords do not match!"
                },
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: postUrl,
                data: $("#passwordForm").serialize(),
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#loading-image").show();
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response == 0) {
                        $("#loading-image").hide();
                        $('#display').html("Incorrect Password");
                        $('#password1, #password2 ').prop('disabled', true);
                    } else {
                        $("#loading-image").hide();
                        $('#display').html("Correct Password");
                        $('#password1,#password2').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

My code for checking old password is

```
$strPassword = $request->password;
$intSessionUserId=Session::get('sessionUserId');

$user = register::find($intSessionUserId);
$strOldPassword = $user->password1;

if($strPassword==$strOldPassword) {
    echo "1";
}
else {
    echo "0";
}
```

Comment: What is code on server side for check password feature?

Comment: postUrl should be  : var postUrl = 'frontend/checkpassword';

Comment: _"Well, what did you expect it to do? What are you trying to accomplish? What have you already tried? **What happened in those attempts? Be detailed: in particular, if something didn’t work, don’t just state that: tell us how it failed. If it threw an exception, what was the exception? (Don’t just give the type – give the error message and say which line threw it. If there’s a nested exception, post that too.)**"_ (quote from:
 [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/))

Comment: @Andreas sorry If I did something wrong. I am new user  to stack overflow.I trying to learning.

Comment: My comment was meant as a tip to improve your question, because _"is not working"_ is a really meaningless problem description ;)

Comment: Wait just a sec. Are you storing plain text passwords in the database?

Comment: @apokryfos yes I am  storing plain text passwords in the database.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords in the database**. Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing

Answer (score 0):

As per mentioned your code in comment

```
public function checkPassword(Request $request) { 
    $strPassword = $request->password;
    $intSessionUserId=Session::get('sessionUserId'); 
    $user = register::find($intSessionUserId); 
    $strOldPassword = $user->password1; 
    if($strPassword==$strOldPassword) {
        echo "1"; 
    } else { 
        echo "0"; 
    } 
}
```

I think you may be compare your plain password with encrypted password. So please check and confirm which encryption method you are using for encrypt password. and encrypt password which is stored in `$strPassword`. This may be resolve your issue.

I see you are using Laravel Framerowk. so you can use below line for password hash comparision.

```
if(Hash::check($strPassword, $strOldPassword)){
    echo "1";
}else {
    echo "0";    
}
```

Refer: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing